# Laravel belongs to Many relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I can't speak English well. I'm Sorry.

There are 3 tables : adverts, advert_categories, categories.

I want to pull data, I get an error
[image: error]

```
Adverts::with(['categories'])->where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvertCategories::class, 'advert_categories', 'advert_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

**advert_categories :**

[image: advert_categories]

**categories:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of belongsToMany method should be your target table not the pivot table in your case is Category,

I suppose that your models are: **Advert** belongsToMany **Category**, and your pivot table is: **advert_categories** the you relationship definition should look like this:

```
public function categories(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'advert_categories', 'advert_id', 'category_id');
}
```

[Laravel docs link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)